# What do I need to change in web config for deploying WCF service on IIS

Tags: wcf

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
           </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webScriptEndpoint>
             <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What do I need to change in web config after deploying my WCF service on IIS?
My code is running with two projects.

Comment: you need to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, and you current setup. What is your problem specifically? You say it is running, but is it not running after you deploy it? Please be more specific so we can help you out.

Comment: After hosting wcf service on IIS server. It is not working. so what  binding related changes i need to do in web config file. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Your binding settings look to be good. As @CitadelCSAlum mentioned it would be nice to what is not working for you here. A few questions that I would ask (1) Do you have [WebGet]/[WebPost] attributes decorated over your service operations for webHttp to work? (2) Do you have an svc file to activate your service?

Comment: Still need more info to help you. There is a ton of WCF configuration options, and the best approach depends on your specific situation. Is this a stand-alone web app or are you trying to host in a MVC app? What specific errrors are you getting? Have you checked the .svclog files? Have you checked the events log? etc

Comment: It is stand-alone application and i am consuming WCF service from Jquery Ajax Call.Below is the error message: "Service called failed: 0No Transport"

Answer (score 0):

Your service and contract name should be a fully qualified names.

check this